# Pygame Collision on Rect

Tags: python, pygame, collision-detection

I'm a student in Computer Programming at my high school and really need help to make the square an obstacle that ships can't enter and bullets disappear once you shoot at the square also for the circle the same thing. And both ships die if they collide with each other. Please help I know my question isn't the best worded but i really need help.

the link to the code is here https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-Pb_T-Vgr3-TnhRY0lvVjJHX0U/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: What exactly is the question? "[...]really need help to make the square an obstacle[...]" sounds more like "please do the coding for me". What have you tried? And what exactly doesn't work? Can you localize it in the code?

Comment: hi howard I've tried if(ship_x > r_x && ship_x < r_x+r_w && ship_y > r_y && ship_y < r_y+r_h) {
   pygame.sprite.collide_rect(square, ship1)
} please help I have to get this done by tomorrow

Comment: Have you tried searching on google or stack overflow for this problem? For such an elementary problem I suspect you will get a lot of solutions.

Comment: Hi Patashu I have googled it but I've just started beginner programming and don't know how to do it. I'd really appreciate it if you could help thanks

Comment: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B-Pb_T-Vgr3-RmhQRE9td2YtM00/edit?usp=sharing i tried fixing it up a little could you please help with the rest

Comment: You should really have asked for help earlier if you were struggling. Looking at your code, you mix tabs and spaces for indentation, you have defined `detectCollision_ellipse` twice (same for the rect functions), You should be calling `IsIn2` in your `detectCollision_ellipse` code. Does your code ever print "collision" or "collision elipse"? What is the problem you're having?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest that you create a GameObject class which extends pygame.sprite.Sprite and both Ship and Bullet classes which extend GameObject. This allows you to then easily add properties that both will need, such as velocity and acceleration, and you can create a collide method that is overridden by both for specific behavior. The added bonus here is that pygame.sprite.collide_rect will work properly as such:

```
if (pygame.sprite.collide_rect(sprite1, sprite2)):
    # sprite1 and sprite2 are colliding!
    # do something, such as calling sprite1.collide(sprite2) 
    # and sprite2.collide(sprite1)
```

So, [pygame.sprite.collide_rect](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.collide_rect) checks if two sprites collide using the Sprite.rect property of each. This functionality could also be recapitulated using [rect.colliderect](http://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html#pygame.Rect.colliderect):

```
sprite1.rect.colliderect(sprite2.rect)
```